# Cannot Add Admin User

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've been following the steps listed in https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/creating-your-first-project to set up a new project, but have run into an issue. When I try to run

```
node app apostrophe-users:add admin admin
```

I get back:

```
That group does not exist.
```

With no other warnings or errors. I'm not sure why the admin group doesn't exist, or how to go about creating it. This is using a fresh database. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group does not exist because, unlike the apostrophe-boilerplate project, your project does not have a `groups` option configured for the `apostrophe-users` module. Perhaps you removed it, or perhaps you started from scratch and did not directly use `apostrophe-boilerplate`.

In this situation, apostrophe does not force any hardcoded groups on you, and instead lets you manually create them via "Groups" in the admin bar.

This is great but there is a chicken and egg problem getting started as you have seen.

The solution to that is to create the group first:

```
node app apostrophe-groups:add admin admin
```

This creates a group called `admin` with the `admin` permission, which allows members to do anything.

Then you can add an `admin` user:

```
node app apostrophe-users:add admin admin
```

Again though, this is only necessary because you either did not use apostrophe-boilerplate at all, or opted to remove the `groups` option from `apostrophe-users`. Which is fine - many sites require that administrators be able to create new groups on the fly, although simpler sites usually don't, which is why we provide an option to lock down just a few instead.

Comment: Ah, that explains it - I did indeed remove the groups option. I also didn't realize you could create groups through the command line - that's handy to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine only writing those commands that are in the link that you have posted. In any case, you can connect to your own database using a program like Compass or Robo3T and check that in the aposDocs collection there is a group called admin.

In the case you don't see the admin group, the easiest way to solve it is to create a new project with the Apostrophe boilerplate again.

Comment: I did end up copying over the admin group option from another existing apostrophe project, but I was more trying to discover the underlying reason why the group did not exist. Like I said above, I did follow the boilerplate setup instructions in the link I posed in my question, and didn't want to set up a whole new project.